# Google maps android API v2 crashes instantly when opened

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am trying to use the google maps API v2 for android and I followed these instructions exactly

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

and everything works fine until I put this code into the layout file

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

once that code is put in the app crashes when opened, this picture also appears on the graphical layout[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be useful to provide stacktrace and some info about the device you are trying to run on.

Answer (score 1):

Use support `Mapfragment`

```
<fragment     
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          />
```

GoogleMap gm;

```
  gm = ((SupportMapFragment(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();    
  gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```